# Prove that 12 is not a divisor of:

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that $12$ is not a divisor of $ 10 ^ 7-10 $.

I did like this:

I rewrote it as $ 9. \frac {10 ^ 6-1} {9} .10 $ and analyzed that this product has no factor $ 2 ^ 2$. Are there any more elegant methods?

Comment: Do you mean divisor instead of multiple? If so, your argument seems fine.

Comment: You mean $10^7-10$ is not a multiple of $12$? The easiest way to see this is probably, $4 \mid 12$, but $10^7 - 10 \equiv -10 \equiv 2$ (mod $4$).

Comment: Hint: $\, 4\mid 4n\color{#c00}{+a}\iff 4\mid a,\ $ and $\ 10^7\!-10 = 4n\color{#c00}{-10}\ $ by $\ 4\mid 10^2\mid 10^7\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

Say $n>1$, then $$10^n-10 = 10\underbrace{(10^{n-1}-1)}_{2k+1} = 2\cdot 5\cdot (2k+1)$$
so it is not divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 2):

You could write

$$10^7 - 10 = (12 - 2)^7 - (12 - 2)$$

If you expand that out, everything is a multiple of $12$ except $(-2)^7 + 2 = - 126$ which is not a multiple of $12.$

Answer (score 2):

$10^7\equiv 0$, $\;10\equiv 2 \mod 4$, so $\; 10^7-10\equiv -2\equiv 2\mod 4$, in other words, $10^7-10$ is not divisible by $4$, hence not divisible by $12$.